# In SqlCommand SqlParameter as cast type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to pass username and password through `SqlParameter`.

But query is not executed.

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT User_ID, Enabled 
              FROM User_Reg 
              WHERE Username = @paramUsername 
                AND CAST(Password AS varbinary(30)) = CAST(@paramPassword AS varbinary(30))";

objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objSqlDbComm.SqlConnectionObject);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUsername", txtUsername.Text);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramPassword", txtPassword.Text);

DataTable objDataTable = objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDataset(objSqlCommand).Tables[0];
```

`objDataTable.Rows.Count` count is 0.

Comment: And where are your Execute command?

Comment: What is `objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDataset`? Please show it also. Have you tried to execute the query in SSMS directly?

Comment: Do you mean that you are getting rows without the CAST?

Comment: I have created SqlDbComm Class And ExecuteDataset is the function where i return datatable

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Library?

Comment: NO its just a class where i open close datbase connection execute dataset etc

Comment: Why you cast to `varbinary`? There s no meaning to cast both parts.

Comment: See Database Field [Password] [varchar] (30) NOT NULL

Comment: @  Hamlet Hakobyan Should i remove cast and do query like this strSQL = @"SELECT *
     FROM User_Reg 
     WHERE User_ID = @paramUser_ID
     AND Password = @paramPassword";

Comment: Yes, you must remove cast. You must also trim text from textbox before adding parameter.

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan :post the answer without Cast i will accept it..

Answer (score 0):

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT User_ID, Enabled FROM User_Reg WHERE Username = '"+txtUsername.Text+"'AND CAST(Password AS varbinary(30)) = CAST('"+txtPassword.Text+"' AS varbinary(30))";
objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objSqlDbComm.SqlConnectionObject);
objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Where is sparameterised SQL  :)

Comment: See First line where you prepare sql query

Comment: Really? Is it paramatrised query? Do you hear about sql injection?

Comment: this will lead to sqlinjection...you can not pass data given from user like this...use parameters..this is very bad way @AnandPhadke

Comment: I already know without parameterised sql it works But i want using parameterised sql

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan -- In that case you should use sql sproc and call it here insted of writing inline queries.. And i guess you need to learn on how to reply to post in professional manner

Comment: @Amit Singh I think there is NO need to show its just a class where i open,close datbase connection execute dataset etc etc

Comment: @AnandPhadke - But, I am sure that you must learn on how to reply to post in professional manner and do not deceive OP with obviously wrong answer.

Comment: what is return type of  
ExecuteDataset

Comment: @HamletHakobyan -- For you kind info,answer is not wrong and I just gave a one more way of doing it. So I guess you did nt even understand the OPs question as u r saying my answer is wrong

Comment: if it return datatable than how u access table[0] in your datatable objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDataset(objSqlCommand).Tables[0];it is accessed lyk this if its is dataset

Comment: @Means -- Did you try creating a sproc which returns USerID and Enabled values from a table for given username & password values to it. Then you can execute that sproc in C#.net using parameterised values

Comment: Here's a dumb question - if you are doing ExecuteNonQuery - where are the results going to?

Comment: Jeff B -- If you need get the data in DataSet or DataTable

Answer (score -1):

```
string Query = @"SELECT User_ID, Enabled FROM User_Reg WHERE Username = '"+txtUsername.Text+"'AND CAST(Password AS varbinary(30)) = CAST('"+txtPassword.Text+"' AS varbinary(30))";
objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, objSqlDbComm.SqlConnectionObject);
objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```